# Get root domain from request

Tags: java, servlets

Consider the below URL as an example.
http://www.test1.example.com

Is there any method by which I can get **"example.com"** as an output. I know there is a method `servletrequest.getServerName()`. It gives me output as **test1.example.com**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), you can get individual parts of the URI using the methods below. You could also use them to reconstruct the URL piece by piece (to help debugging, or other tasks), like this:

```
// Example: http://myhost:8080/people?lastname=Fox&age=30

String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +   // "http" + "://
             request.getServerName() +       // "myhost"
             ":" + request.getServerPort() + // ":" + "8080"
             request.getRequestURI() +       // "/people"
            (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" +
             request.getQueryString() : ""); // "?" + "lastname=Fox&age=30"
```

So [`request.getServerName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29) is the closest we got to you need.

#### The "root domain":

For the "root domain", you'll have to work through the `String` returned from `getServerName()`. This is necessary because the Servlet would have no way of knowing ahead of time what you call "host" or what is just a domain like `.com` (it could be a machine called `com` in your network - and not just a suffix -, who knows?).

For the pattern you gave (one third+secondlevel+com/net), the following should get what you need:

```
String domain = request.getServerName().replaceAll(".*\\.(?=.*\\.)", "");
```

The above will give the following input/outputs:

```
www.test.com       -> test.com
test1.example.com  -> example.com
a.b.c.d.e.f.g.com  -> g.com
www.com            -> www.com
com                -> com
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...but in your example you have host just myhost..please reconsider it when your URL is as I mentioned in my question which has subdomain in it.

Comment: @AlexandruRada The example in the question only works for `.com`, `.net` and such. For what you want, you'll have to use: `String domain = request.getServerName().replaceAll(".*\\.(?=.*\\..*\\.)", ""));`. Notice that the same way that doesn't work for `.co.uk`, this one will work for `.co.uk` (and similar), but will not work for `.com` and such.

Comment: or use `^[^\.]*\.(.*)$` to just remove the first sub-domain

Comment: if there is a proxy server, it does not work. request.getServerName() getting the local proxy server IP.

Comment: @AhuraMazda usually, proxies add a header that indicate the server of the original request. Perhaps you can look for that

Comment: This method won't work when we get more than one top-level domain like "example.com.au"

Comment: @HungryMind you have to use a different regex for that. See the second comment above.

Answer (score 19):

We have more reliable way of doing the same. There is google library "guava".
Add following dependency in your pom.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
     <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then try

```
InternetDomainName.from("subdomain.example.co.in").topPrivateDomain().toString()
```

This will give you `"example.co.in"`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as a simple String manipulation:

```
String A = "http://www.test1.example.com";
String B = A.substring(A.lastIndexOf('.', A.lastIndexOf('.')-1) + 1);
```

There is no standard way obtain `example.com` from `a.b.c.example.com` because such a transformation is generally not useful. There are TLDs that don't allow registrations on the [second level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain);  for example  [all `.uk` domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk). Given `news.bbc.co.uk` you'd want to end up with `bbc.co.uk`, right?

Answer (score 2):

For a `HttpServletRequest request` you can use :

```
 String domain = request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI(),"");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

void Func() {
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println (ia.getHostName());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding but this question was basically on how to get root domain in Java and I believe this is for JSP.