# How to get the complete path of a page in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I am trying to get the complete path of a page in order to convert it into a url.

What I have tried so far,

```
private static String PAGE = "/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar";
private static String URL_TO_OPEN;

public static String getUrl(Set<String> pages, ResourceResolver resolver){

  Resource htmlPage = resolver.getResource(PAGE);

  if(htmlPage != null){

  URL_TO_OPEN = htmlPage.getPath().concat(StringConstraints.DOT).concat(StringConstraints.HTML);
  return URL_TO_OPEN;
  }
}
```

In this case,
URL_TO_OPEN = "/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html"

But what I require is, e.g., "http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html"

Can someone please help me out with how I can get it to be in this format instead, that is get the [hostname]:[port] as well?

http://[hostname]:[port]/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html

Comment: Try this https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/externalizer.html

Comment: Externalizer is the recommended way to go, as pointed out above. If you don't intend to use this feature, you can think of retrieving this from servlet sling request object. Code snippet here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17241575/4173416

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using the **Externalizer** OSGi Serive

Add the mappings in the externalizer service configuration

```
local http://localhost:4502
author http://localhost:4502
publish http://localhost:4503
```

To get the URL

```
String myURL = externalizer.externalLink(resolver, Externalizer.LOCAL, PAGE) + ".html";
```

This will create the URL

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/externalizer.html)